# How to loop through range of dates in Swift3 (for each day between x and y, call on a method and pass in that day as a date value)

Tags: swift, xcode, date, for-loop, swift3

I'm trying to do the following:

for each day between startdate and enddate, call on this method and pass in that day as the date...etc.

This seems like something that should be straightforward but everything I'm trying is just not working out. I am unfamiliar with swift (this is a project I'm thrown into), but it seems like something as easy as a for loop is more complicated than I thought it was.

A lot of what I tried researching is either deprecate methods, or it's more focused on calculating days between two dates or something like that which I don't need.

p.s. I may need a fairly large range of dates (more than a year), so I think there would have to be consideration for things like leap years with certain methods?

If anyone can help that'd be really appreciated, thank you

Any additional info that I'm not sure if is relevant: I am using xcode version 9.4.1, ios 11.4. I have seen that people use c in these projects but I'm not too sure how that would work, it would be great to have just the swift code for this

Comment: And why are you using Swift 3 when it’s two major versions behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty simple. Just get the difference in days, create a range with it and loop through the number of days, add it to the start date and call your method. Note that I am using noon time as it is recommended for time insensitive calendrical calculations:

```
extension Date {
    var noon: Date {
        Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
}
```

---

```
let startOf2020 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2020, month: 1, day: 1).date!.noon
let now = Date().noon
let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startOf2020, to: now).day!   // 302

(0...days).forEach { n in
    let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: n, to: startOf2020)!
    print(date.description(with:.current))
}
```